# Java Delete Button GUI shrink array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I am trying to create a Delete button that would remove an item. The goal here is when the delete key is selected by the user it removes the current entry and copies all remaining items to a new temp array. Please be forewarned that I am still learning and simply looking for assistance in the right direction, though solutions are also welcome as I can learn from them too. The error I am getting is quite long and based on my previous experiences, I imagine is has to do with using a null check, I am just not sure where if at all it should be provided.

Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Bookstore$8.actionPerformed(Bookstore.java:435)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

and here is the code for the button

```
    JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);
    deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p) 
        {

            //#1
            Book[] tempBook = new Book[inventoryBook.length - 1];

            //#2
            Book itemDelete = inventoryBook[bookIndex];

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < inventoryBook.length; i++) 
            {
                if (inventoryBook[i].getISBN() != itemDelete.getISBN()) 
                {
                    tempBook[j] = inventoryBook[i];
                    j++;
                }

            }
            sortArray(tempBook);
            inventoryBook = tempBook;
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
        }
    });
```

please know that this error only occurs when the Delete button is selected by the user. There are no compile errors.

below I have included the entire code for compiling or seeing everything else.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

// Begin class Book
class Book
{
private String isbn;
private String title;
private String authorName;
private int yearPublished;
private String publisherName;
private double price;

NumberFormat usCurrency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

public Book (String isbn, String title, String authorName, int yearPublished, String publisherName, double price)
{
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.authorName = authorName;
    this.yearPublished = yearPublished;
    this.publisherName = publisherName;
    this.price = price;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setISBN (String ISBN) //set ISBN
{
    this.isbn = ISBN;
}
public String getISBN () //get ISBN
{
    return isbn;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setTitle (String Title) //set Title
{
    this.title = Title;
}
public String getTitle () //get Title
{
    return title;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setAuthorName (String AuthorName) //set AuthorName
{ 
    this.authorName = AuthorName;
}
public String getAuthorName () //get AuthorName
{
    return authorName;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setYearPublished (int YearPublished)//set YearPublished
{
    this.yearPublished = YearPublished;
}
public int getYearPublished () //get YearPublished
{
    return yearPublished;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setPublisherName (String PublisherName)
{
    this.publisherName = PublisherName;
}
public String getPublisherName ()
{
    return publisherName;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setPrice (double Price)
{
    this.price = Price;
}
public double getPrice ()
{
    return price;
}


//toString method
public String toString ()
{
    return "ISBN:" + "\t\t\t" + isbn + "\n" +
           "Title:" + "\t\t\t" + title + "\n" +
           "Author's Name:" + "\t \t" + authorName + "\n" +
           "Year Published:" + "\t \t" + yearPublished + "\n" +
           "Publisher's Name:" + "\t\t" + publisherName + "\n" +
           "Price" + "\t\t\t" + usCurrency.format(price) + "\n";
}
} // end class Book


//Begin class EBook
class EBook extends Book
{
private String webSite;


// constructor
public EBook (String isbn, String title, String authorName, int yearPublished, String publisherName, double price, String webSite)
{
    super(isbn, title, authorName, yearPublished, publisherName, price);
    setWebsite(webSite);
}

//accessor methods
public void setWebsite(String webSite)
{
    this.webSite = webSite;
}
public String getWebsite ()
{
    return webSite;
}


public double discount ()
{
    return (super.getPrice()) * .10; // EBook discount of 10%
}

public String toString ()
{
    return super.toString() + "Website:" + "\t\t\t" + webSite + "\n" +
                    "EBook Discount:" + "\t\t" + usCurrency.format(discount()) + "\n";
}

} //end EBook class



public class Bookstore
{
private static Book inventoryBook[] = new Book[5];
private static NumberFormat usCurrency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
static int bookIndex = 0;
private static Book [] newBookInventory = new Book [inventoryBook.length + 1];

public static JTextArea prepareDisplay (Book myBook, JTextArea myTextArea)
{
    myTextArea.setText("");

    myTextArea.append(myBook.toString());

    return myTextArea;
}

public static Book [] sortArray(Book[] books)
{
    // Step1
    String[] titles = new String[books.length];

    // Step2
    Book[] sortedBooks = new Book [books.length];

    // Step3
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
    {
        titles[i] = books[i].getTitle();
    }

    // Step4
    Arrays.sort(titles, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    // Step5
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < titles.length; j++)
        {
            if (books[i].getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(titles[j]))
            {
                sortedBooks[j] = books[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return sortedBooks;
}

public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] books)
{


    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
    {
        if(books[i]!= null)
        {
            total += books[i].getPrice();
        }   
    }   
    return total;
}



public static void main ( String args [])
{




    //initial array of Bookstore before anything is added
    inventoryBook [0] = new EBook ("0075260012", "David goes to School", "David Shannon", 2010, "Shannon Rock", 11.98, "http://www.tinyurl.qqwert67o9");
    inventoryBook [1] = new Book ("7423540089", "No David!", "David Shannon", 2009, "Shannon Rock", 12.99);
    inventoryBook [2] = new Book ("0743200616", "Simple Abundance", "Sarah Breathnach", 2009, "Scribner", 14.99);
    inventoryBook [3] = new EBook ("78137521819", "The very hungry caterpillar", "Eric Carle", 2005, "Philomel Books", 13.99, "http://www.tinyurl.fguopt8u90");
    inventoryBook [4] = new Book ("9781416987116", "We are going on a bear hunt", "Michael Rosen", 2009, "McElderry", 15.99);




    for (int i = 0; i < inventoryBook.length; i++)
    {
        newBookInventory[i] = inventoryBook[i];
    }

    inventoryBook = newBookInventory;


    //inventoryBook = sortArray(inventoryBook); 

    final double inventoryTotal = calculateInventoryTotal(newBookInventory);

    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(30, 30);
    textArea.setText("");
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    JButton firstButton = new JButton("First");
    buttonPanel.add(firstButton);
    firstButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            bookIndex = 0;
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
            textArea.append("\n Total Inventory Value: " + "\t\t" + usCurrency.format(inventoryTotal));
        }
    });

    JButton previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
    buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
    previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(bookIndex == 0) 
            {
                bookIndex = inventoryBook.length - 1;
            } 
            else 
            {
                bookIndex = bookIndex - 1;
            }
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
            textArea.append("\n Total Inventory Value: " + "\t\t" + usCurrency.format(inventoryTotal));
        }
    });

    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(bookIndex == inventoryBook.length - 1) 
            {
                bookIndex = 0;
            } 
            else 
            {
                bookIndex = bookIndex + 1;
            }
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
            textArea.append("\n Total Inventory Value: " + "\t\t" + usCurrency.format(inventoryTotal));
        }
    });

    JButton lastButton = new JButton("Last");
    buttonPanel.add(lastButton);
    lastButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            bookIndex = (inventoryBook.length - 1);
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
            textArea.append("\n Total Inventory Value: " + "\t\t" + usCurrency.format(inventoryTotal));
        }
    });


    JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
    buttonPanel.add(searchButton);
    searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            boolean matchFound = false;
            String searchCriteria = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Book Title");

            for (int i = 0; i < inventoryBook.length; i++)
            {
                if (inventoryBook[i].getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(searchCriteria))
                {
                    matchFound = true;
                    bookIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (matchFound)
            {
                prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Book Title " + searchCriteria + " does not exist.");
            }
        }
    });

    JButton modifyButton = new JButton("Modify");
    buttonPanel.add(modifyButton);
    modifyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Book Title", inventoryBook[bookIndex].getTitle());
            if (title != null)
            {
                String isbn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter ISBN", inventoryBook[bookIndex].getISBN());
                if (isbn != null)
                {
                    String authorName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Author's Name", inventoryBook[bookIndex].getAuthorName());
                    if (authorName != null)
                    {
                        String yearPublished = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Year Published", inventoryBook[bookIndex].getYearPublished());
                        if (yearPublished != null)
                        {
                            String publisherName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Publisher Name", inventoryBook[bookIndex].getPublisherName());
                            if (publisherName != null)
                            {
                                String price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Price", inventoryBook[bookIndex].getPrice());
                                if (price != null)
                                {
                                    inventoryBook[bookIndex].setTitle(title);
                                    inventoryBook[bookIndex].setISBN(isbn);
                                    inventoryBook[bookIndex].setAuthorName(authorName);
                                    inventoryBook[bookIndex].setYearPublished(Integer.parseInt(yearPublished));
                                    inventoryBook[bookIndex].setPublisherName(publisherName);
                                    inventoryBook[bookIndex].setPrice(Double.parseDouble(price));

                                    prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    buttonPanel.add(addButton);
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String isbn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter ISBN");
            if (isbn != null)
            {
                String title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Title");
                if (title != null)
                {
                    String authorName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Author's Name");
                    if (authorName != null)
                    {
                        String yearPublished = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Year Published");
                        if (yearPublished != null)
                        {
                            String publisherName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Publisher Name");
                            if (publisherName != null)
                            {
                                String price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Price");
                                if (price != null)
                                {


                                    Book newBook = new Book (isbn, title, authorName, (Integer.parseInt(yearPublished)), publisherName,(Double.parseDouble(price)));
                                    inventoryBook[newBookInventory.length - 1] = newBook;
                                    prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);
    deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p) 
        {

            //#1
            Book[] tempBook = new Book[inventoryBook.length - 1];

            //#2
            Book itemDelete = inventoryBook[bookIndex];

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < inventoryBook.length; i++) 
            {

                if(inventoryBook[i].getISBN() != itemDelete.getISBN()) 
                {
                    tempBook[j] = inventoryBook[i];
                    j++;
                }

            }
            sortArray(tempBook);
            inventoryBook = tempBook;
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
        }
    });





    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel (new ImageIcon("GoblinBooks.jpg"));
    JPanel logoPanel = new JPanel();
    logoPanel.add(logoLabel);

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    centerPanel.add(prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea));




    //for (int i = 0; i < inventoryBook.length; i++ )
    //{
    //  textArea.append(inventoryBook[i] + "\n");
    //}



    textArea.append("Total Inventory Value: " + "\t\t" + usCurrency.format(inventoryTotal));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(logoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
} // end class Bookstore
```

Comment: Which line is line 435 exactly? Where does `inventoryBook` come from? Is it initialized?

Comment: Is `inventoryBook` initialized before you call `inventoryBook.length`? If it 's not, then you'll get a `NullPointerException`. Another variable to check if null is `bookIndex`.

Comment: I have attached the complete code. The inventoryBook is initialized.

Comment: I believe the issue must be lying somewhere in the code to delete the item and copy the array items. I am just not sure what I am doing wrong. If I remove the code for this button all together everything works.

Line 435 is   if (inventoryBook[i].getISBN() != itemDelete.getISBN())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the same problem as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663966/java-add-button-gui-grow-array), one or more of the elements in your array is `null`

You declare you arrays as...

```
private static Book inventoryBook[] = new Book[5];
private static Book [] newBookInventory = new Book [inventoryBook.length + 1];
```

You then copy the contents if `inventoryBook` to `newBookInventory`, one element at a time...

```
for (int i = 0; i < inventoryBook.length; i++)
{
    newBookInventory[i] = inventoryBook[i];
}

inventoryBook = newBookInventory;
```

Which means that both `inventoryBook` and `newBookInventory` have a single `null` element at the end of the array.

You then iterate over `inventoryBook`, access the `getISBN` method of each element, without first checking to see if that element is `null`

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < inventoryBook.length; i++) 
{
    if (inventoryBook[i] != null) {
        if (inventoryBook[i].getISBN() != itemDelete.getISBN()) 
        {
            tempBook[j] = inventoryBook[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

It might even be worthwhile checking `itemDelete` to ensure it's not `null`, but I didn't read that much of the code